# 802.1X OSX Yosemite not Authenticating

Tags: macos, wifi, 802.1x

Trying to connect to my schools wireless network, but the 802.1X Authentication wont finish. It also says that I have a self-designated IP.

Comment: No error message?

Comment: Nope, it just keeps loading @KevinGrabher

Comment: Nothing in the system log files?

Comment: How would I get that? @Garex

Comment: The self-assigned IP says you are connected to the router but do not have Internet access.

Comment: How can I resolve this? Why is it not authenticating/taking forever(literally) to authenticate 802.1X @Buscar웃

Comment: you can not, but you can talk to the IT person.